# material-ui-next table exceeds container width and it's not scrollable

Tags: material-ui

im starting a new project using react, react-router and material-ui-next.

Im facing a problem that i've trying to find with no success.

[table exceeds containing component boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkcbO.png)

Structure is in this way

```
return (
            <Paper>
                <Fragment>
                    <CommonToolbar reload={getAnns} />
                    <Typography variant="title">Announces</Typography>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
```

styles is defined this way

```
const styles = {
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10
    },
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    input: {
        marginRight: 10
    },
    select: {
        marginRight: 10
    }
}
```

What im trying to achieve is a table contained on the screen, and if it exceeds the screen, the table should be horizontally scrollable, but always contained inside the Paper Component.

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding `overflowX: "auto"` in your paper container?

JSX:

```
return (
            <Paper className={classes.paperContainer}>
                <Fragment>
                    <CommonToolbar reload={getAnns} />
                    <Typography variant="title">Announces</Typography>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
```

Your styles:

```
const styles = {
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10
    },
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    input: {
        marginRight: 10
    },
    select: {
        marginRight: 10
    },
    paperContainer: { margin: "10px", overflowX: "auto" }
}
```